# Open pdf in new tab (FireFox and IE 8) using EXTJS, JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, pdf, extjs, extjs4

I'm using EXTJS, i have a link, which is used to open a PDF file.
The problem is that the pdf is not opened in the navigator, but it's downloaded ! 
The code i'm using is the following (which i found in stack ! )

var win = window.open(url, '_blank');

win.focus();

what i'm messing ?

Comment: IE8 doesn't ship with a PDF renderer so by itself it is unable to "render a PDF in a tab". If you have Adobe Reader or another PDF renderer installed they often add a plugin into the browser to perform this action. If you don't have the plugin then the file will download. Some people, including myself, actually disable the inline-mode on purpose. Depending on your version of Firefox you might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser decides whether to open the file or show it inline (in the new tab) depending on received HTTP headers.

To download, server sends this header:

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="somefile.pdf"
```

To show inline, server sends this header:

```
Content-Disposition: Inline
```

Comment: how can i send this from the server ? 
In my case, what i retrun from the server is the file name and the path!

Comment: I don't know which server language you use. In PHP, that I use, there is function `header(...);` that you can use to send headers. I have written an example that does opposite - sends headers to download the file - but I think you can adapt it to your needs. It is here: http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#downloading-file

Comment: emm .. i was not very clear in my first port, in fact, what i return from the server, is the path name, and the pdf file is not in the server,  in fact it is in a directory in my computer ! 

So what i return is a string la this : 'D:/DATA/myPDFFile.pdf'

Comment: Then it is fully in hands of the browser and you can do nothing about it either in Ext or server. Probably the browser settings apply in this case. BTW, it sounds very strange that remote server would return a local path - how can the server know the file is there?

Comment: Actually i made a mistake, in fact, the solution you proposed work just fine for me.
Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 1):

Sample code of what I used:

```
{
xtype: 'button',
html: '<p class = "i-custom-right-menu-items-text">'+'Download Application 
       form'+'</p>',
cls: 'i-custom-right-menu-buttons',
width: '80%',
padding: '2 0 0 10',
iconCls: 'd-ball-modal-right-menu crtmenu',
handler: function () {
    window.open('./resources/MYPDF.pdf', '_blank');}
}
```